# Show & hide loader in landing page without api call or set-timeout in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am struggling somewhere in react app with redux, searched a lot but didn't get the desired solution that is why I am posting the question here, 
 So my problem is that I have to show a loader when the page loads and when the whole HTML loads loader should be hide,  below is my code

```
class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    stayLoggedIn: false,
    isLoading: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ isLoading: false });
   }, 2000);
  }
```

rendering html based on `isLoading` but currently i have used set-timeout show and hide the loader I want to know is there any solution to make it work without set-timeout, Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Vivek, you can set "isLoading"  true in ComponentWillMount and turn it false in componentDidMount .

Comment: @Bhawana I think `constructor` will be called before `ComponentWillMount` Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: The basic answer is to remove the setTimeout function and just setState in componentDidMount. If the render still looks too fast for you (like the state hasn't actually loaded from redux yet), then you'll need to show us more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DovRine this is the code what I am trying to do and apart from this code I am showing the Loader based on `isLoading` condition

Comment: Yes vivek you are right! you can one thing set in component 
this.state.isLoading? lodingScreen : <your component>, and remove settimeout from componentDidMount simply put this there : this.setState({ isLoading: false });

Comment: @Bhawana I have already tried this but there is blank white screen showing for long than the loader is showing for some microsecond  than the login page shows that is why I put the set-timeout

Answer (score 0):

1. `setTimeout` is just an asynchronous operation, when you call the setState function, React compare the old state and new state, and trigger a render to your component based on the new state.
2. When you have a local state to your component, you inject the redux state as a props to your component, this way don't trigger a render when you have local state, you need to use the `componentWillReceiveProps` method and call a `setState` method to change your local state by using `setState` based on new props.

   Note: `componentWillReceiveProps` method work until `React v17`

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const delay = async ms => await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

class Loader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ isLoading: nextProps.isLoading });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ border: "1px solid #999", padding: "10px" }}>
        Loader component
        <div>Loading: {String(this.state.isLoading)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false
    };
  }

  async asyncOperation() {
    // Show loader
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    // Async operation, like fetch, etc...
    await delay(1000);

    // Hide loader
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Loader isLoading={this.state.isLoading} />
        <br />
        <button
          onClick={this.asyncOperation.bind(this)}
          disabled={this.state.isLoading}
        >
          {this.state.isLoading ? "Waiting..." : "Call async operation"}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<LoginScreen />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why you have used `setTimeout` ? I don't want that.

Comment: You can delete it if you want, just set loading to false after my async delay method

Comment: can u please modify your code to mine (class names) so that I can understand it more clearly

Comment: thanx for the modification but I don't want any button click also , just a simple landing page, whenever we hit URL the loader must show & when the whole DOM rendering is done the loader must hide  that's it .

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting it right "when the whole HTML loads" you want to show a loader while your react app is rendered into the browser. for that what you can do is:

1- If you have bootstrapped your project with Create React App 
     - Go to public folder, there is a file named index.html
     - It will have  a `<div>` element into which your entire react application is rendered by the web bundler which will be webpack in this case. 
     - Inside of this div write a loader like this

```
   <div id="root">
    <section class="loader">
      <h1 class="heading">INITIALIZING</h1>
      <p class="sub-heading">bear with us ...</p>
    </section>
  </div>
```

So whats happening here is when you wrote this piece of code

`ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`

It basically injects your react app into this root document element and as soon as your application is bundled up, the entire html is loaded in the browser and injected into this div it will replace your loader and your login page will be visible

And here's the CSS for the loader animation

```
<style>
.loader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.loader .heading {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: heart-beat 4s infinite ease-in;
  z-index: 1;
}

.loader .sub-heading {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #4b4b4b;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes heart-beat {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
}

</style>
```

2- The second option would be to create your react application without CRA but in that case you'll again have an index.html and you can repeat the above steps.